# How to change font color on an ajax button? Php and Yii 1.1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have a small question some of you might help me with instantly.

I am currently working on a website where all the buttons need to be the same color. However, through some dumb reasons (lack of Skill in my case) I have created an ajaxButton and now need to change the text color of said button to orange.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this and thought some of you might help me with my little dilemma. I have no css skills whatsoever and though that there must be a method where I can directly change said color as I desire.

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton('Create',
    Yii::app()->createUrl("path/to/action/create"),
    array(
        'type'=>'POST',
            'dataType'=>'json',
            'url'=>'js:$(this).attr("href")',
            'success'=>'js:function(html) {
                jQuery("#myModal .modal-content").html(html.view);
                $("#myModal").modal();
            }',
        'buttons'=>array(
            'update'=>array(
                'options'=>array(
                    'title'=>'Create Something',
            'cache'=>false,
        ),
        array('data-toggle'=>'modal', 'data-target'=>'#myModal'),
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

So this would be the button that needs a new text color. I really hope you can help me with  this. Thanks for your time everyone.

Comment: Forgive me, but this seems like a very simple matter of CSS. Try to do some research on that. There's also some pretty neat CSS frameworks/libraries out there that can make your button(s) look nice and stylish (Bootstrap for instance). I would simply make a class selector in css `.orangeButton{ background-color: orange; }`. Add that class to your html button and voilá!

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the advice, mate. I am really new to this whole programming thing, so I really have no idea on how to do this whole thing. But I will make sure to learn asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order create css class then use ajax to add after success like:

**CSS**

```
<style>
.color{
color:orange;
}
</style>
```

**JS:**

```
'success'=>'js:function(html) {
                jQuery("#myModal .modal-content").html(html.view);
                $("#myModal").modal();
                $("#Button").addClass("color");
            }',
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! Works without any problems whatsoever!